# XHR failed loading: POST on AJAX request (in React)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, passport.js

I don't think React has anything to do with this, but just in case, that's what I'm working in. I'm receiving the error `XHR failed loading: POST` when submitting an AJAX request to /login. I am trying to create a login route using Passport JS, and I know that the route is receiving the data because it will console.log as `{ email: 'myemail', password: 'mypassword' }` and `typeof` returns object.

```
this.handleLoginSubmit = () => {
  let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xml.open("POST", "/login", true);
  xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xml.send(JSON.stringify({email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password}));

  xml.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xml.readyState === 4) {
      console.log('here')
      console.log(xml.response);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT** Here is the route:

```
router.post('/login', emailToLowerCase, function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
if (err) {
  console.log('error')
  return next(err);
}
if (!user) {
  return console.log('no user!')
}
req.logIn(user, function(err) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  console.log('logging in')
  return res.send(req.user)
});
})(req, res, next);
});
```

**EDIT** Here is the form:

```
<form id='login-form' className="small-form" className='nav-div' onSubmit={props.handleLoginSubmit}>
<div className='nav-div'>
  <li className="nav-item">
      <input type="email" required name="email" placeholder='Email' className='form-control' value={props.email} onChange={(e) => props.handleEmailChange(e.target.value)}/>
  </li>
  <li className="nav-item">
      <input type="password" required name="password" placeholder='Password' className='form-control' value={props.password} onChange={(e) => props.handlePasswordChange(e.target.value)}/>
  </li>
  <li className='nav-item'>
      <input type='submit' value='Login' />
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend using the `fetch` API if possible, I've found that the `XMLHTTPRequest` interface is confusing for me. `fetch` is much simpler to use. If you still have the same problem with `fetch`, I can help debug.

Comment: @Sidney I was originally going to use fetch but then realized it's not implemented at all in IE?

Comment: [Here's a fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) so that you can use `fetch` in IE.

Comment: I second the fetch API, there are some examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch keep in mind some older browsers will require an adapter / polyfill.

Comment: @Sidney Can someone explain to me _why_ `fetch` is so much better? I get that the syntax is easier to understand, but then you have to use the pollyfill as well for cross-browser compatibility, so you need to do double essentially. Are there other reasons to use `fetch` opposed to XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: For me, the effort to include the polyfill is *drastically* outweighed by the ease of use. A single expression sends a request with `fetch`.

Comment: So what is the error, did you look at the network request?

Comment: @epascarello I'm not getting an error on the server.

Comment: So what is the statusText? what is the status? How is the method called?

Comment: @epascarello `console.log(xml.statusText)` isn't returning anything.

Comment: Well how about the other two things I asked?

Comment: @epascarello sorry, updated the post

Comment: `I was originally going to use fetch but then realized it's not implemented at all in IE?` ... neither are arrow functions, but you're using them

Comment: @JaromandaX Did not know that, but also not relevant to the post.

Comment: well you do not cancel the form submission....

Comment: one thing I notice is that you are handling a `submit` ... but you aren't preventing the default submit action

Comment: `this.handleLoginSubmit = e => { e.preventDefault(); ...rest of your code };`

Comment: @JaromandaX I wasn't sure if I need to do that and tried it and didn't solve problem. Not getting an error but also not getting a response from server.

Comment: check the developer tools network tab ... is the request sent, is a response returned?

Comment: @JaromandaX request status is failed. could it have to do with stringified JSON?

Comment: any further information than "failed"? surely the browser says more than that - to be honest, I can't see in your "route" anything that handles `email` or `password`

Comment: @JaromandaX It stalls. Under the response tab it just says Failed to load response data. Yet terminal is still logging the login info. Sorry there isn't more info.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
if (!user) {
  return console.log('no user!')
}
```

You are not sending any response to UI. Not sure how the `next(err)` processes the response, but at lease in case `user` is not found you want to send some error back to the client, like:

```
if (!user) {
  console.log('no user!');
  return res.status( 404 ).json({ message: 'User not found' });
}
```